# Como faço uma pesquisa em um site externo?

Tags: php

Como posso fazer pesquisa de CPF/CNPJ no SERASA utilizando PHP, pesquisei, mas não achei muita coisa de como fazer, mas achei serviços online que funciona, alguém pode me dizer como posso fazer isso.

Comment: Bom provavelmente o SERASA deve fornecer uma API, provavelmente paga. Agora se existir algum site que você já consegue essa informação. Qual é o site? Onde vc consegue pesquisar?

Comment: Este é um exemplo de Site: https://www.consultaserasa.com.br

Answer (score 1):

Para consultar no SERASA você precisa integrar com essa webserver:

```
https://www.soawebservices.com.br/integracao/manuais/default.aspx
```

Comment: Certo estou dando uma olhada nesse Site, e pelo que parece eu tenho que fechar um serviço com eles onde eles irão me fornecer as ferramentas necessárias para incrementar no meu sistema?

Comment: Sim. Todas as API que encontrar para buscar no Serasa vai precisar fechar serviço. Pois todas são pagas

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Eu sou novo em programação e tenho muita coisa para aprender. Agora vou estudar um pouco como funciona o uso de API com PHP.

Comment: Mais uma pergunta! Só existe essa empresa que fornece esse tipo serviço? pois estou pesquisando no google e não acho outra empresa!

Comment: @JonatasM só conheço essa.

Comment: Ok, Muito Obrigado!